# tensorflow - variables not initializing after importing a graph to merge with another graph and perform training

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning

My goal is to merge graph A which has training done on it with graph B. I can't seem to initialize the variables coming from graph A.

export graph_def and meta_graph

```
  tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph, './tmp', 'model.pb', as_text=False)
  tf.train.export_meta_graph(filename='./tmp/mod.meta', graph=graph, clear_devices=True)
```

import to graph b's graph.

```
  tf.import_graph_def(graph_def) 
  tf.train.import_meta_graph(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tmp') + '.meta')
```

initializing variables in session

```
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tmp'))
  init_op = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name("init")

  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(init_op)
```

following command reports that there are no uninitialized variables. if I ran the command before the initializer commands from above it displays the variables from graph A and B are uninitialized.

```
print(sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()))
```

output error

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value import/b3
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is you can save a checkpoint + metagraph and load that as opposed to loading the graphDef + metagraph.

```
# saving a checkpoint + metagraph
with tf.Session() as sess:
   tf.Saver().save(sess, save_path='./tmp/model.chkpt', global_step=global_step)
   tf.train.export_meta_graph('./graph/final.meta', clear_devices=True)

# loading checkpoint + metagraph
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./graph/final.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
   new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tmp'))
```